# Parsing XML processing instructions in PySpark

Tags: pyspark, databricks, apache-spark-xml

I am trying to parse one XML file that has processing instructions using `databricks` `spark-xml`.
Example XML

```
<books>
    <?SOURCE sample_file?>
    <?DATE 12/01/2022?>
    <book>
        <title>Spark Tutorial</title>
        <desc>Spark Tutorial for beginners</desc>
        <author>John C</author>
        <details>
            <price>1234</price>
            <pagecount>1000</pagecount>
            <chapters>
                <chapter>C1</chapter>
                <chapter>C2</chapter>
                <chapter>C3</chapter>
            </chapters>
        </details>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Scala</title>
        <desc>Scala Tutorial for beginners</desc>
        <author>John C</author>
        <details>
            <price>599</price>
            <pagecount>1000</pagecount>
            <chapters>
                <chapter>C10</chapter>
                <chapter>C20</chapter>
                <chapter>C30</chapter>
            </chapters>
        </details>
    </book>
</books>
```

Is there any way to parse those XML processing instructions `SOURCE` & `DATE`?
I can read other XML tag values but not able to read the processing instructions.

I tried with `lxml` library & able to read the **processing instructions** but not able to do the same using `spark-xml` library.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems spark-xml library ignores the XML processing instruction. Reference https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/pull/412